# How to configure 3.5 inch touchscreen on raspberry pi running android?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, arm, raspberry-pi3, touchscreen

I was making a smartphone using an RPI 3B and I am running Emertia os.
Can someone help me get the touchscreen feature working?

Answer (score 0):

I tried looking for a few 3.5" touchscreen.
Different touchscreens may have different setup methods.
Some may even need to install specific 'modified' Linux.

The code below is one of the installation code on the guide (without specific Linux).
You can have a try.

```
sudo rm -rf LCD-show
git clone https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git
chmod -R 755 LCD-show
cd LCD-show/
sudo ./LCD35-show
```

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Miuzei-Raspberry-Display-Monitor-Resolution/dp/B07H2CR49S Here's the screen I ordered, thanks for the help.

Comment: You better ask for the seller if they have any installation guides.